# MATLAB Coder: sparse matrix

Tags: c++, c, matlab, sparse-matrix, matlab-coder

MATLAB Coder seems to be fancy and can speed up MATLAB code much by converting the code into C/C++ or MEX.. But it seems that it does not support sparse matrix, or the matlab function `sparse` which is essential to my code. Does anyone have any idea about how to overcome this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Write your own mex function?

Comment: Isn't the calculation core of sparse code already written in C?  I'm not familiar with Coder, but I suspect it only speeds up your own iterative code.  It isn't going to speed up calls to builtin MATLAB code.

Comment: You could also just generate MEX code for the portions of your MATLAB code which doesn't use sparse to speed those portions up.

Answer (score 1):

The [eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html) can be used to handle the Matlab function sparse and it is in c language.

As said by "libill", You could also just generate MEX code for the portions of your MATLAB code which doesn't use sparse to speed those portions up.

And for sparse part use above library.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of Matlab coder maybe wrong but I think it is a tool that convert your Matlab codes to C/C++ codes. I am not sure performance optimization is the goal of Matlab coder.

Take a look at suitesparse. It's a C Library that handle a lot of sparse operations. The Matlab "\" operator in the case of sparse matrix actually uses suitesparse. So I think it may be easier for you to modify the Matlab generated C codes.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I just am not sure what do you mean by converting. I assume you mean writing your own mex function.
Sparse packages usually deal sparse matrices differently and Matlab has also its unique way to treat them.
However mostly they use CSC (or CSR) format. Matlab is also saving the matrix as CSC format.

You can look at lots of sparse packages mex functions to see how it is done. 
The point is Matlab will not let you save explicit zeros in its sparse data structure.
DO NOT try to save explicit zeros on Matlab mex function. Matlab will choke on you!